# Connecting to kafka restproxy (confluent) on HTTP

Tags: oracle, apache-kafka, confluent-platform

I'm currently working on a project that requires connecting to oracle eventhub which is a Oracle's version of kafka. The systems contacting the restproxy wouldnt accept the self signed certificate hence i'm trying to do either : 
1- turn off https and allow for http connections to kafka
2- import a signed certificate i generated

unfortunately i cant locate the certificate store neither do i know how to or even if it is possible to have the rest proxy run on http

Comment: The solution was more simple than i thought, obviously Oracle Eventhub rest-proxy uses nginx for service exposure, few modifications to the configuration file and i was able to both remove https and allow for a certificate that i had issued.

Comment: Please answer your questions below rather than leave them in the comments

Answer (score 0):

The solution was more simple than i thought, obviously Oracle Eventhub rest-proxy uses nginx for service exposure, few modifications to the configuration file and i was able to both remove https and allow for a certificate that i had issued